# Email to Salesforce

Tags: email

We have a email templates that our clients can decide to send to MPs on their behalf. We want to use Email to Salesforce so that this email is attached to the contact and the MP in our system. Is that possible?
My understanding of Email to Salesforce is that the email has to come from myself, otherwise it cannot be attached to the contact, is that correct?

Tia.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional Acceptable Email addresses in your personal settings, but that is not going to work well if you have many clients sending these emails.

Your other option would be to use an Inbound Email service to process the emails. That would require writing some code where you would determine who the email is being sent to, and insert an activity to their contact. Your template would then just CC or BCC the email address that you set up with your email service. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com